# Object Reference casting vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object, reference, casting, instance

I have no idea on how to cast an object that type was 'Object' to a user defined class type.

I have a private instance variable:

```
Private studyType as Object
```

What i need to do is to instantiate this object from an event handling method. And no, not to instance `new Object()`.

Basically it would look like this:

```
studyType = new VCEOnly()
```

However, I am only allowed to use the `Object` class subs and functions as the type was defined as `Object`. So i need to cast it to `VCEOnly` class type so i can access its subs and functions.

Basically, `studyType` needs to be casted from `Object` to `VCEOnly`. I am not allowed to pre-define `studyType` as `VCEOnly` when declared.

Comment: The big question here is *why* can't you declare `studyType` as `VCEOnly`?

Comment: Because there are other classes that may be instantiated using the name, 'studyType'. That is why i needed to declare it object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use:

```
dim studyType as Object = new VCEOnly()    

...

dim studyTypeVCE as VCEOnly = nothing
if trycast(studytype,VCEOnly) IsNot Nothing then
   studyTypeVCE = DirectCast(studytype,VCEOnly)
   '... do your thing
end if
```

the if statement checks if the object can be casted to the wanted type and if so variable of type VCEOnly will be filled in with a cast of studytype.

Comment: Yea, but I can't declare the reference type as VCEOnly. It needs to be delcared as Object. StudyTypeVCE must be casted to VCEOnly after that.

Comment: yeah, but it needs to be declared with Object. I have other classes that will utilise the same name.

Comment: code is adjusted to your case i think. declaration as object, and in a later stage cast to do typed actions.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use the same object reference variable. I can't utilise another variable and I assign the newly casted object to it. studyType is like the real big variable that will be used in many other forms and classes later on.

Comment: the only thing you do is create a new variable off a new type but with the same reference. so at the end your changes will also be available in de variable of type object you first edited.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant? Could you please rephrase? Thanks.

Comment: because you are using classes it uses references instead of values. so if i have a variable1 and a variable2 that equals to variable1. in memory this means there is one object (the actual object) and there are two references to that object. so if you change values with variable2 you can access the changes also with variable1. Because they both link to the same object in memory.

Comment: oh thanks, I have figured out a different way now because of this new information you told me! :D :D :D!!!!

Comment: can you rate the comments? :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Use CType to cast an object from one type to another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Something like this should do it:

```
Dim studyType as Object
Dim studyTypeVCE as New VCEOnly
studyTypeVCE = Ctype(studyType,VCEOnly)
```

or you can just do this:

```
With CType(studyType, VCEOnly)
    .SomeVCEOnlyProperty = "SomeValue"
End With
```

Comment: what do you mean 'abc'? In my event handling code, studyType needs to be casted from its original 'Object' to 'VCEOnly'

Comment: @ApoorvKansal - I have edited my answer which should make this clearer.

Comment: Is there a way to cast studyType to 'VCEOnly' after it has been declared? Because I am using the name studyType in many other functions and studyType can actually later contain a different object like VCALOnly. I don't want to create a new variable and then assign the casted object.

Comment: @ApoorvKansal - You can't change the type of something after it has been declared, but you can replace all instances of studyType to CType(studyType, VCEOnly) so you don't have to declare another object but this is not good practise to do a lot of type conversion